# Blinking rectangle in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to learn pyGame. And I ran into a problem. I have a rectangle which can be moved with arrow buttons. Then I created another thread which generates smaller rectangles which can be picked up. But when I run my game, the small generated rectangles blink too much. How can I make them be stable? I think I dont understand time concept here well. Could someone explain me etc

My code:

```
import pygame
import random
import threading
import thread
import sys
import time

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
done = False
is_blue = True
entityList = []
x = 30
y = 30

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
class Entity():

     def __init__(self, x, y):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y

     def getX(self):
         return self.x

     def getY(self):
         return self.y

     def drawStuff(entityList):
     #   pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 100, 0), pygame.Rect(55, 45, 10, 10))
         for x in range (0, entityList.__len__()):
             pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 100, 0), pygame.Rect(entityList[x].getX(),     entityList[x].getY(), 10, 10))
         pygame.display.flip()
         clock.tick(60)


class EntityManager(threading.Thread):

     def __init__(self):
         threading.Thread.__init__(self)

     def run(self):
         while True:
             entityList = generateEntities()
             drawStuff(entityList)

     def endJob(self):
         thread.exit()
         time.sleep(2)


def detect_collision(x,y):
    if x > 340:
       x -= 1
    if y > 240:
       y -= 1
    if y < 0:
       y += 1
    if x < 0:
       x += 1
    return x,y

def generateEntities():
    itemlist = []
    for x in range (0,4):
        x = random.randint(1,339)
        y = random.randint(1,239)
        entity = Entity(x,y)
        itemlist.append(entity)
    return itemlist

entityList = generateEntities()
a = EntityManager()
a.setDaemon(True)
a.start()

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    is_blue = not is_blue

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= 1
        x,y = detect_collision(x, y)
    if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += 1
        x,y = detect_collision(x, y)
    if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= 1
        x,y = detect_collision(x, y)
    if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += 1
        x,y = detect_collision(x, y)

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    if is_blue: color = (0, 128, 255)
    else: color = (255, 100, 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(x, y, 60, 60))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: What do you mean 'blink too much' ?

Comment: well those rectancles simply blink. I mean my main rectancle (which I control by keyboard) moves smoothly. But those rectancles that EntityManager creates, blink.

Comment: Like lagging or? BTW you really must NOT use sleep function in pygame

Comment: You can say that it might look like it is lagging. I think it has something to do with time, because when I modify clock.tick value in drawStuff method then it laggs more or less

Comment: @qqvc and why should i not use sleep function? I thought sleep function would be useful to make those dots to stay there for some time and then they change their positions

Comment: ok I specify my question, how do I make those generated rectangles stay for some 10 seconds and then change their position?

Comment: I edited my answer check it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clock.tick()` actually means FPS (frames per second); instead of changing it, change another variable. 
Watch [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNjSyBlbl_Q&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAjkwJocj7vlc_mFU-4wXJq&index=9), it might help you understand FPS.

Issues about smoothness are sometimes about the size of your object and how many pixels you are moving it when key events are `True`. Be careful about that; imagine you have a little box and you are trying to move it. If you move it with big steps, it seems 'laggy', but if you move it with little steps then it may look smoother. Hope you understand what I mean.

For your second question please check [this documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html).

Comment: well I did used delay function but then those rectangles didnt appear at all anymore

Comment: You should check some examples in internet how to use that function.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out now. OMG, I feel such an idiot after this. But I forgive myself that I am also doing parallell learning of Python. I used to code in Java more.

Anyway: problem was that my drawStuff function drew things in function but when it left this function, it did nothing. Changes were made locally. I solved this problem by using global keyword. I made in my code changes that thread computes entity coordinates and then main loop does update. This leads me to another idea that maybe there should be some game info object which gets updated all the time and all rectangles info go to that game info object.

Anyway, soon I will edit this post code too to see what i did